# storage_path flutter plugin returning IOS version(15.2) in imagesPath

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Plug-in functions return version in imagepath.

same behaviour in all these functions getImagesPath() ,getVideoPath(),getAudioPath(),getFilePath().

**Plug in:** https://pub.dev/packages/storage_path , storage_path: ^0.2.0

```
Future<void> getImagesPath() async {
String imagespath = "";
try {
  **imagespath = await StoragePath.imagesPath;** // return IOS Version (Example: Ios 15.2)
  var response = jsonDecode(imagespath);
  print(response);
  var imageList = response as List;
  List<FileModel> list = imageList.map<FileModel>((json) => FileModel.fromJson(json)).toList();

  setState(() {
    imagePath = list[11].files[0];
  });
} on PlatformException {
  imagespath = 'Failed to get path';
}
return imagespath;
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you missed the comment "Only for Android" in the readme. It seems iOS isn't implemented. Contact the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Actually, I missed reading the Readme file. This plug-in is only available with android.

**ONLY FOR ANDROID**

[image]